# Ensure AMD modules load before content scripts

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

### Overview

I'm trying to convert a site over to [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) with  [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org). Much of the site relies on global variables defined in a separate module (mainly utility methods). This leads to serious difficulty for developers, since the modules do not always load before the content scripts.

### Ideal outcome

I'd like a way to prevent these in-page scripts from being parsed until certain modules have loaded, so team members can slowly remove them as time allows.

### Research

1. I noticed that [curl.js](https://github.com/cujojs/curl#can-curljs-work-with-non-amd-javascript-files) has a way to load some scripts in sync mode.
2. I could not find anything similar for RequireJS 2+, though I thought it used to be supported. (My git foo is not strong enough.)

### Caveats

1. While I'm aware that I can load the modules via script tags while in dev mode, I'd rather not since this would require listing the modules in two places.

### What I tried

So I tried generating a polling solution, which runs a crudely timed while loop, then breaks
out to run a callback. Here's my implementation:

```
(function (global) { // Making this into a global, so I don't need to wait for the loader's extra timeout. 
    var undef;

    /**
     * Simple args getter.
     *
     * @param {*} arg Used if defined.
     * @param otherwise Used if arg is not defined.
     * @return {*}
     */
    var arg = function (arg, otherwise) {
        return arg !== undef ? arg : otherwise;
    };

    /**
     * Locks up the main thread as soon as the current thread completes.
     *
     * @param {number} time
     */
    var lock = function (time) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var start = +(new Date),
                current = 0;
            console.log('Locking thread at %d', start);

            start += time;
            while (start > (current = +(new Date))) {
                console.log('tick');
            }

            console.log('Unlocking thread at %d', current);
        }, 0);
    };

    /**
     * Locks up the main thread until a condition is met, releasing it
     * momentarily to allow other "threads" to advance.
     *
     * @param {Function} condition
     * @param {number} [checkInterval=50] How long
     */
    var lockThreadUntil = global.lockThreadUntil = function (condition, checkInterval, releaseDuration) {
        checkInterval = arg(checkInterval, 50);
        releaseDuration = arg(releaseDuration, 0);

        var id = setInterval(function () {
            if (!condition()) {
                lock(checkInterval);
            } else {
                clearInterval(id);
            }
        }, releaseDuration);
    };

    define(function () {
        return lockThreadUntil;
    });
})(this);
```

On page (I tested w/ a module that create a global):

```
(function (global) {
    lockThreadUntil(function () {
        var isLoaded = !!global.path && !!global.path.toModule;
        if (!isLoaded) {
            return false;
        }

        console.log('Is loaded!');
        return true;
    }, 1000);
})(this);
```

And in an in-content script:

```
console.log('Was needed!');
```

I was hoping this would result in the DOM advancing very little while giving the script time to load, thus allowing it to make it into the parse stack ahead of the in-content scripts. Unfortunately, it seems the in-content scripts are firing first.

### Wrapup

I'm open to suggestions. The options I'm thinking of include (both seem terrible):

- Gritting my teeth and using script tags.
- Swallowing the RequireJS load method and replacing w/ an xhr implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the require js [**shim**](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) capability for your legacy code and allowing RequireJS to load everything (including your in-DOM script tags).  Shim allows you to essentially create an AMD version of a legacy browser-globals file.  The shim configuration allows you to specify dependencies of and among shimed modules as well as identify their exported browser global.

Say you have legacy files **A** and **B** as script tags in your DOM where **B** depends on (and script tag comes after) file **A**.  Also say both **A** and **B** depend on AMD-formatted utility module **Lib**. Remove the script tags for **A** and **B** from the DOM and add a require js configuration block similar to the following:

```
requirejs.config({
  shim: {
    'A': ['Lib'],
    'B': ['Lib', 'A']
  }
});
```

This should essentially make RequireJS load your legacy scripts after your AMD module library has been parsed.  I've simplified the example here to assume that all of your library AMD modules can be required via a single super-module **Lib**.

Take a read through the [shim documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) as it also explains how you can tell require js what your modules export (in terms of global objects) to make the shim that much more complete.

**Caveat:** This will only work in development mode. If you try and run the RequireJS optimizer the result will not work due to the dependency of shimmed modules on standard AMD modules (as noted [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)).

Also, this solution will require that you manually jig the order of each in-DOM script tag using dependencies in the shim config where necessary (like I made B follow A by making it depend on A).  In the past you could have used the RequireJS *order!* plugin but it was [removed in favour of shim](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.0#wiki-shim) in RequireJS 2.  This isn't exactly a bad thing because it can help you work out the true dependencies between your scripts and make full conversion to AMD a little easier in the future.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't solve my problem. Won't the first module load *after* the in DOM scripts load?

Comment: @Josh, sorry, I wasn't clear.  I suggest replacing the in-DOM script tags with `shim`ed module definitions and allow RequireJS to manage loading everything.  You won't have to touch the code of your non-AMD scripts but you would have to remove the script tags from the DOM.  I've edited my answer to be more clear.

Comment: I'm not sure what the shim is giving me here. The scripts are _in_ the content, so I need their deps to load before the content, which seems impossible w/o either a sync xhr or some way to block the browser's dom parser. I think the miscommunication is that the scripts that depend on the AMD module are not in a separate file. (I wish they were, but legacy code is, well, _legacy_.)